# Using @Primary with spring-context-indexer

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I am trying to add `spring-context-indexer` into the libraries of my project. However, when running an integration test I would like to not use a Bean from a dependency (`SystemConfiguration`), but override it using `@Primary` to return a `new MockSystemConfiguration()`. That doesn't seem to work with the spring-context-indexer.

Here is my test

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CustomTestSpringConfig.class)
class SpringDataConfigurationTest {

    @Test
    void applicationContextCanStart() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

And CustomTestSpringconfig

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = SystemConfiguration.class)
public class CustomTestSpringConfig {
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "SystemConfiguration")
    public SystemConfiguration systemConfiguration() {
        return new MockSystemConfiguration();
    }
}
```

The real `SystemConfiguration` is defined in a different jar that already has the `spring-component-indexer` in it.

```
@Component("SystemConfiguration")
public class SystemConfigurationImpl implements SystemConfiguration {
```

What is happening is the real `SystemConfiguration` Bean is being used instead of the one annotated with `@Primary`.

Comment: do you create a bean of type `SystemConfiguration`? is it your project's dependency or external?

Comment: Updated the question with the definition of SystemConfiguration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's your project's dependency (and you import this dependency into your app but you have a control over the dependency) it makes sense to declare a bean with conditions. F.e.:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(SystemConfiguration.class) // mock bean in tests would be of the the same type so this one is skipped
SystemConfiguration systemConfiguration() {
    return new SystemConfigurationImpl();
}
```

If you don't have a control over the dependency and you need the test bean it's natural to run tests with `test` profile, so you can play with `@Profile("test")` and `@ActiveProfiles("test")`.

Good examples here: [Spring Profiles](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/)